# Api Gateway can't invoke Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

Following [this tutorial on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-configure-event-source.html), I hit a roadblock when trying to test the api through the web console (as many others did):

`Thu Nov 10 22:54:48 UTC 2016 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function`

I've read every relevant post on SO and AWS forums I could find, but can't figure out how to grant permission to the API Gateway to invoke the Lambda function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Web Console Method:

Thanks to [this mate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4LM_jw5zzs) I found a quick fix:

Go into the web console and select

The resource method > Integration Request > Pencil next to Lambda Function > Check mark next to lambda function (don't change the name)

A popup window should warn that you are granting permissions to the API to execute the lambda function.

---

### API Method:

Also, thanks to Richard Downer for this code explanation:

A resource policy is different from an IAM Policy, setting the IAM policy will not work.

You need to use the Add-LMPermission api call after creation of Write-AGIntegration.

Here is an example:

`Add-LMPermission -FunctionName myfunction -Action lambda:InvokeFunction -Principal apigateway.amazonaws.com -SourceArn arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:IAMAccountNumber:*/*/POST/apiendpoint -StatementId description`

Comment: Amen. I called AWS the other day after hours of struggling and they said, oh, our documentation is wrong, do this...

Comment: How can you add this policy with terraform or through the console?

Comment: I imported API via Swagger...but forgot to update the permissions for lambda invocation, this fixed my issue!

Comment: you can add this through terraform via this resource:

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "<resource_name>" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIgatewayInvocation"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "<function_name>"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account_id>:*/*/*"
}