# Terraform - how to attach IAM role to invoke Lambda to API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

## Question

How to attach the assumable role with the lambda invocations to an API Gateway API or all methods?

[Create an API Gateway API for AWS Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) tells to attach an IAM policy to invoke Lambda:

> This means that, at minimum, you must attach the following IAM policy to an IAM role for API Gateway to assume the policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

> An API Gateway assumable role is an IAM role with the following trusted relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Research

It looks [lambda_permission](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html) can attach per method basis but not sure if there is a way to be able to invoke any method "*".

### Update

[Api Gateway can't invoke Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538493) tells a way to attach from UI per method/function.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As in [Specify Lambda permissions for API Gateway REST API](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html#specify-lambda-permissions-for-api-gateway-rest-api), set source_arn to the execution_arn of the API should do.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.example.arn}"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Per deployment
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # The /*/*  grants access from any method on any resource within the deployment.
  # source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.test.execution_arn}/*/*"

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Per API
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # The /*/*/* part allows invocation from any stage, method and resource path
  # within API Gateway REST API.
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.execution_arn}/*/*/*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gw" {
      name = "your-api-gw-name"
      description = "your api gateway description"
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambda_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"

  #your lambda function ARN
  function_name = "arn:aws:lambda:${var.aws_region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:lambda-function-name"   
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.aws_region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gw.id}/*/POST/"
}
```

**note:-** declare **aws_region** variable in your **variable.tf** file with your region value.